# How do I install the J2EE SDK on 10.04?

Tags: installation, 10.04, java, jdk

I get the following error when I try to install j2eesdk on ubuntu 10.04

```
./j2eesdk-1_4_03-linux-ml.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have searched google, and all sites provide fixes that dont work

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search for J2EE sdk results in 1.4 showing up right on top. Sad that google search does not show the latest sdk. Even the oracle site does not mention anywhere that 1.4 is old and is a newer version.

During install, the first step is install location. I provide that. After install this folder is empty. Now I need to figure out where the jar's are.